# PTAC through brick wall

Tags: hvac

I am doing a project where I bought old building and converting in to apartment unit. The building has brick wall and was thinking of putting PTAC like they have in hotel. Initially I was thinking of putting mini split but that seems to be more expensive. I need advice if someone has put PTAC through brick wall. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "If someone has done it"? I can advise you that somewhere, someone has done this. Please [edit] your post to explain what, exactly, your question is. Without more details, this is far too broad for us to answer. Please take the [tour] and look through the [help] (especially on asking) to see how things are a bit different around here.

Comment: The question is not broad at all but a simple structural question.

Answer (score 1):

If you think a mini split is two expensive you have not compared the structural work and possible engineering stamps required for a package unit. The unit will take at least a 3’ wide hole usually ~18” tall this requires reenforcement of the brick and this would be for a studio style, a 2 bedroom unit will be even more because of the brick work.
Having installed both I can do mini split in a couple of hours drilling the ~ 2” hole to the outside is the hardest part (both will require power so we will call that part equal for the new circuit.
Commercial properties require additional B.S. or oops governmental permits in some cases and have to be done by a contractor licensed for the work, where a home owner can do there own work.
To fully compare systems get a quote to put the package unit in the mechanical work alone can double the cost of install.

Comment: +1 for "additional B.S. or oops governmental permits"!